# Pyomo: Defining a new set as a set operation

Tags: optimization, pyomo

Given:

```
from pyomo.environ import * 
model = AbstractModel() 
model.I = Set()
model.J = Set()
```

I need to define a new set K = J - I

I tried

```
model.K = model.J - model.I
```

But it does not seem to be an option. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: According to the Pyomo documentation, Section 4.2 Operations,  such set operation (-) is possible as stated. My problem must be elsewhere then. I would not mind if the question is deleted.

Comment: It can often help to provide the error message that you encounter.

Comment: I was not encountering an error message, but rather my optimization model was not behaving as I expected. It turned out that I miss-typed one of the constraints.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better you to write

```
model.I - model.J
```

rather than

```
model.K
```

If you want to use the expression model.K, I recommend that you enter the appropriate information for model.K in rootdata like model.I and model.J.

Comment: I agree, the first way is clearer since it does not require for you to remember an additional variable.